# I've got the imgAreaSelect plugin working..how do I use the x and y coordinates to update the image in the database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Using the dimensions and coordinates returned by the jQuery plugin imgAreaSelect, how to I update the image in the database to reflect this selection? I have a tempImage and Image field in the database, so I want to take the image in tempImage, let the user make a square selection, then upload that square image to the Image field. Perhaps using PHP? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can u post a plunker?

Comment: what is plunker? What the plugin returns is x and y coordinates of a selection of an image. How can I use these coordinates to crop the image?

Answer (score 0):

A post from the PHP manual:

```
<?php
// Create a blank image and add some text
$ini_filename = 'test.JPG';
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($ini_filename );

$ini_x_size = getimagesize($ini_filename )[0];
$ini_y_size = getimagesize($ini_filename )[1];

//the minimum of xlength and ylength to crop.
$crop_measure = min($ini_x_size, $ini_y_size);

// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
//header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$to_crop_array = array('x' =>0 , 'y' => 0, 'width' => $crop_measure, 'height'=> $crop_measure);
$thumb_im = imagecrop($im, $to_crop_array);

imagejpeg($thumb_im, 'thumb.jpeg', 100);
?>
```